# Are contracting related topics off topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I was referring to the question here:

[Is it professional to cut out a middle-man in a contract chain?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1029/change-contracting-company)

This was flaged off-topic.

There are others of course which seems to be fine so far:

[Should I get a contract when offered paid trial work?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/416/should-i-get-a-contract-when-offered-paid-trial-work)

[When should I inform management that I have been approached by a competitor?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/618/when-should-i-inform-management-that-i-have-been-approached-by-a-competitor)

[Can I charge for email support as a freelancer?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/908/can-i-charge-for-email-support-as-a-freelancer)

Are freelancing and contracting related questions off-topic?

Answer (score 6):

**Stack Exchange is for members of the workforce navigating the professional setting.**

First line of the [FAQ](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/faq#questions). Yes, I would say it fits.

Comment: Contractors are professionals

Answer (score 5):

This question should absolutely be on topic.  While it needed cleaned up even in its old form  it was on topic.  It also was not to localized for anyone else to get value from the answers.

Answer (score 0):

The way this question was originally phrased invited rather localised answers to his specific situation.

The scope of [your answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/1030/148) was substantially wider than that of the question itself, but without improvement the usefulness of your answer to others in the future would be limited.

Incidentally, I was one of those who jumped the gun and voted to close. I even made the newbie mistake of automatically selecting the most popular close reason rather than thinking for myself.

Thinking about it though, there is the kernel of a good question in there, and hopefully my edit will have helped it to take root.

If I'd seen the comment about this meta post before casting my close vote, I might have tried to improve the question first, so I think the lesson to be learnt is to try and see the value in a question before dismissing it rather than after.

Comment: What is *local* about CompanyA contracting CompanyB? This can happen anywhere?  BTW: the flags (the first 2) didn't say *too localized* - they say *off-topic*!

Comment: Your edits does make the question better - essentially the title was lousy i agree. However, we must all realize that we are here to build good content, any chance to improve content should be attempted over just dumping questions on the *closure* dustbin.  Thanks for the edit, and let's aim to make this site a great place.

Comment: That's the spirit! Many Thanks ...

Comment: @Chad - If there were a way to [rescind close votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/915/138432) I would agree more. Alas the hysteresis in the close/reopen cycle means that once a question is closed, it becomes very difficult to gather enough support to reopen it, even if the question has been *substantially* improved.

Comment: @MarkBooth If it gets closed you can just flag a moderator and ask them to reopen it considering the recent edits made to improve the question since.

Comment: @maple_shaft - I'm not sure if I'm the only one, but I really try to be sparing in my use of moderator flags. I guess it's better to bring things that need highlighting to the attention of moderators, but I hate to take up their valuable time unless I'm *sure* it will add value.

Comment: @MarkBooth As a moderator on Server Fault I would say ***flag away***!  Right now our mods are the community team, and they *are* pretty busy, but glancing at flags and making a quick decision to act or ignore doesn't take long.  If you become a nuisance they'll tell you :)